# USB charger for Li-ion batteries

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging

I'm designing a PCB for charging single-cell Li-ion batteries via USB. Hereby, charging via USB from a computer and from a wall adapter should be supported. As a charger IC, I consider using the following part:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25606.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&DCM=yes&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Feu.mouser.com%2F&distId=26

The charger IC automatically detects via the D+ / D- singals which kind of wall adapter is connected or if a computer is connected and limits the charging current accordingly. The screenshot below shows the different cases.

[image]

I wonder why the case of USB100 (a limit of 100 mA) is missing. I thought old USB ports from computers may only be able to supply 100 mA. Wouldn't it pose a risk using this charger IC if one would connect it to a USB port than can only supply 100 mA?

Comment: The USB port capable of supplying up to 100mA would limit the current to that amount anyway

Comment: @SimonSultana Thanks. Actually, that's what I'm not sure about. Because some time ago I read that a port that can only supply 100 mA not necessarily limits the current to this amount, but can be damaged if trying to draw more current.

Comment: double check the USB port has sufficient protection circuitry. A while a go I posted this, worth a read : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/472930/207946